# What is the difference between the flexibility and stretching tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there a purpose for stretching other than flexibility? Is there a way to achieve flexibility other than stretching?

Both of these tags have empty wiki entries and are rarely used. I propose making them tag synonyms.

Comment: I'm not convinced yet - semantically they are different, and you could talk about flexibility but not stretching. Let's hear what people have to say....

Answer (score 1):

My impulse is that flexibility is about increasing the range of motion whereas stretching involves the warming up on the muscles and tendons, which can be used to increase flexibility, but might also be used to simple avoid injury within the already-achieved range of motion.

Since this is martial arts site, I'd probably say that `stretching` has a potential ambiguity with [submission stretches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_wrestling_holds#Stretches), but that's probably addressable on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lesser increase in range of motion through reciprocal inhibition techniques - usually in the form of isometric resistance without stretching...  but yeah, for all reasonable intents and purposes these ought to be synonymous.